# How can I allow one-way video communications with Agora?

Tags: android, agora.io

In an Agora two-person communication, how can I allow only one participant to receive the video from the other user?

I can implement this with the audio without a problem. But with video, I do not receive any event when the remote user stops sending video for example (onRemoteVideoStateChanged not fired).

I tried setting up the client role to broadcaster on both sides but the one-way video still does not work:

```
mRtcEngine.setClientRole(Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote user should be using the `muteLocalVideoStream()` method to mute their video (https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a949cd7044eec55ffd0b63ad3004db756).

You can then observe for this event using the `onRemoteVideoStateChanged()` callback with state as 0 and reason as 5 (https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#a93ebe88d2544253bf4b13faf34873131).

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks